# Open materialize modal by clicking on jsf commandButton

Tags: java, jsf, materialize

I want to put a `outputText` inside a `modal` that is opened when a `commandButton` is clicked.

I tried this code:

```
<div class="row section">
  <div class="col">
    <!-- Modal Trigger -->
    <h:commandButton value="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1" action="#{someBean.someMethod}" />                                
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h:outputText value="#{someBean.someData}" />
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And js:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
    $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
  });
```

However, this doesnt work and i just started using materialize with jsf

Comment: are you using any JSF extension ?

Comment: regardless of JSF extension, **why** would you apply a 'leanModal' to a commandButton???

Comment: @SubodhJoshi no, I just imported javax.faces on pom and materialize on head tag

Comment: @Kukeltje i tried to follow this code: http://codepen.io/mblarsen/pen/JXPRjY

Answer (score 0):

you can try this using the tag decoration.

add to your ui:composition the xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"

after, use the html 'a' tag

```
div class="row section">
  <div class="col">
    <!-- Modal Trigger -->
    <a href="#modal1" jsf:actionListener="#{someBean.someMethod}">
        <i class="material-icons">view_list</i>
        <p:ajax update="modal1" />
    </a>                                
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h:outputText value="#{someBean.someData}" />
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
  </div>
</div>
```